# is there any solution for authentication with vuejs and django?

Tags: python, node.js, ajax, django

I use the `Django` framework as backend and `vue.js` and `webpack` for the frontend. to implement authentication, send a request via `ajax` to `Django` and want to keep session for next requests but can not keep session.

I use the `request` node module for send request and use the `jar` to keep session but get error 403 again. it means `jar` does not keep the session for this user.

in vuejs:

```
var request = require('request');

get_jar(){
    if(this.jar){
        return this.jar;
    }
    this.jar = request.jar();
    return this.jar;
}

send_ajax(url, data, method, callback){
    request(
        {
            url: url,
            method: method,
            form: data,
            jar: this.get_jar(),
        },
        function(err, res, body){
            callback(err, res, body)
        });
}
```

in django:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, 'dispatch')
class Login(View):
    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        email = request.POST.get('email', None)
        password = request.POST.get('password', None)
        user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
        if user is None:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'incorrect username or password'}, status=403)
        else:
            login(request, user)
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'user logged in'})
```

a decorator for check user log in:

```
def user_login_required(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return method(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'user not recognized'}, status=403)
    return wrap
```

can somebody help me, please?

Comment: please be specific about what's not working. do you see an error? what exactly doesn't work? "but can't" doesn't really tell us much.

Comment: @dirkgroten I edited the question. my problem is jar does not keep session and for any request i got error 403.

Comment: Where's the code where you save the session cookie in the jar? If you login using ajax, the cookie doesn't automatically get added to the jar because you're not loading a page. It's in the JSON response headers..

Comment: @dirkgroten I saw response headers but it does not contain any session. how can i get session?